# how to pass primary key id to mongoDB using logstash

Tags: mongodb, oracle, logstash

We are migrating data from Oracle to MongoDB using Logstash. When dumping data, we want to move primary key constraint from oracle to MongoDB instead of creating a different primary key in MongoDB.

Please guide me on how to achieve this.

Comment: We can choose to assign unique values to `_id` instead of relying on MongoDB to default it. Could you configure Logstash to map the Oracle primary key column(s) to `_id`?

Comment: @APC, Thanks. It worked for me

Comment: Good guess on my part. I suggest you write up your solution as an answer, to help future Seekers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer.

We can choose to assign unique values to _id instead of relying on MongoDB to default it. Could you configure Logstash to map the Oracle primary key column(s) to _id